# How to add Facebook login account on website using JSF 2.0

Tags: java, facebook, jsf-2, primefaces, facebook-login

I am trying to create a website where it has "login or register" feature. Nowadays, every website gives login with facebook/twitter or gmail account. I would also like to do the same thing. I am creating my website using JSF 2.0 + primefaces. Could you please guide how do I go about the same? I am totally new for this application.

Thanks for the help in advance. Looking for great thoughts.

Comment: You don't actually use JSF to make the login, you embed already existing components provided by each third party (Facebook, for example) instead. Check [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/) to get you started. If you have any problem, show us what you've got so far and we'll gladly help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this easily by following these steps:

1. Create a Facebook application on developers.facebook.com
2. Fill in the "Web-site with facebook login" section on the app
   configuration correctly.
3. take a look at to the [Facebook Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)
4. On the view layer, use FB Javascript SDK. When a user reaches your
   page , call FB.getLoginStatus() to check if the user    already has
   a valid Facebook login . If not use FB.login() with a button to to log the user in
   and get user credientials.
5. Post the received facebook id and oAuth token into your backing bean
   after a successful login using a RemoteCommand component of
   PrimeFaces.
6. You can use [RestFB](http://www.restfb.com/) library to talk to Facebook Graph API on the
   backend of your web application to reach the necessary user data and
   merge your application's user account with the user's facebook
   account.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there any example available?

Comment: I dont know a full example for this. Maybe I can write a blog post for this in the near future.

You can find FB JS SDK examples at the Facebook link I provided, A PrimeFaces RemoteCommand example exists in the PrimeFaces documentation and the documentation for RestFB includes many examples. Combining them is left as an exercise :)

Comment: @OzanTabak, have you written the blogpost with examples?

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) for this, there are implementations for Facebook, Google, Twitter and so on. [Here](http://oauth.net/code/) you can find some useful libraries for Java although I have no experience with them.